# AndroidTest with PACKAGE_USAGE_STATS permission

Tags: android, automated-tests, android-espresso

Our goal is to use AndroidTest(AndroidJUnit4) to run automatic tests.

We have used this code to grant permissions when SDK >= 23

```
public static void grantPermission(String permission) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        if (!hasPermission(permission))
            getInstrumentation().getUiAutomation()
                                .executeShellCommand("pm grant " + getTargetContext().getPackageName() + " " + permission);
    }
}

@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    grantPermission("android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE");
    grantPermission("android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE");
    grantPermission("android.permission.CAMERA ");
    grantPermission("android.permission.INTERNET");
    grantPermission("android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE ");
    grantPermission("android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE");        
    grantPermission("android.permission.PACKAGE_USAGE_STATS");       
}
```

The method is fine for

```
android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
android.permission.CAMERA
```

Although in the Settings/Security/Apps with usage access, our app is on, but when we use this code to check permission, it still doesn't have that permission.

```
AppOpsManager appOps = (AppOpsManager)context.getSystemService(Context.APP_OPS_SERVICE);

// return MODE_DEFAULT, not MODE_ALLOWED
int result = appOps.checkOpNoThrow("android:get_usage_stats", android.os.Process.myUid(), context.getPackageName())
```

How can I do to succeed this goal?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have tried many approved. Finally, we succeeded.

The approved was use "adb shell input tap [x], [y]" to simulate tap, so it is like human tap the screen to trigger the switch.

This is the code us use.

```
private void grantPermission() throws InterruptedException {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        Context context = InstrumentationRegistry.getTargetContext();
        final AppOpsManager appOps = (AppOpsManager) context.getSystemService(Context.APP_OPS_SERVICE);

        // check if the app doesn't have permission
        if (appOps.checkOpNoThrow("android:get_usage_stats", android.os.Process.myUid(), context.getPackageName()) != AppOpsManager.MODE_ALLOWED) {
            UiAutomation automation = InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().getUiAutomation();

            //Open UsageAccessSettingsActivity
            automation.executeShellCommand("am start com.android.settings/.Settings$UsageAccessSettingsActivity");
            Thread.sleep(1000);

            //Open the setting of the first app
            automation.executeShellCommand(String.format("input tap %s %s", dpToPx(100), dpToPx(138)));
            Thread.sleep(1000);

            //Tap permit usage access
            automation.executeShellCommand(String.format("input tap %s %s", dpToPx(100), dpToPx(164)));
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }
    }
}

public static int dpToPx(int dp) {
    return (int) (dp * Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics().density);
}
```

We have tried 6 AVDs on SDK 23 and 24 with hdip, xhdip and xxhdip. All works.

**UPDATED[2/10]:**

We found another easier way to do it. use "adb shell appops" commend.
This is ours code.

```
@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        Context context = InstrumentationRegistry.getTargetContext();
        final AppOpsManager appOps = (AppOpsManager) context.getSystemService(Context.APP_OPS_SERVICE);

        if (appOps.checkOpNoThrow("android:get_usage_stats", android.os.Process.myUid(), context.getPackageName()) != AppOpsManager.MODE_ALLOWED) {
            InstrumentationRegistry
                    .getInstrumentation()
                    .getUiAutomation()
                    .executeShellCommand("appops set " + context.getPackageName() + " android:get_usage_stats allow");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your app has usage stats enabled. You can check this by launching the Usage Stats Activity. add this to your code on your `onCreate` method or possible on a button click:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_USAGE_ACCESS_SETTINGS);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: we did to launch the Activity and users can permit the usage access, but our goal is to run automated-tests, so we want to do it programmatically to simulate that the user already grants the permission.